# How wide or narrow should cabal dependency version constraints be?

Tags: haskell

I recently uploaded a Haskell project to Hackage, but I was uncertain how narrow or wide I should make my dependency version constraints in the cabal file. Are there any guidelines for this?

Comment: I hope you find what you're looking for, but asking for written guidelines could be construed as an off-topic request for an off-site resource.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I deleted the word "written"

Comment: As at least one answer notes, this question has been the subject of enormous controversy over the past... long time. There are blog posts, Reddit threads, mailing list threads, too voluminous to link or summarize. An index of the various positions could be useful, but I'm not sure this is the right forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Haskell Package Versioning Policy](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Package_versioning_policy), which gives clear guidance.

But I should add that these are not universally accepted, and cause regular heated debates, especially the upper version bound on dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your dependencies are. If you're lucky, they correctly apply [semver](http://semver.org/) conventions, in which case you should set your dependency to the earliest minor version your projects works with and anything after that, but before the next major version.